# Magento - Unable to create a custom template for custom menu item

Tags: magento

I created a custom menu item in the magento admin panel. But i couldn't create a template for that. i am getting a '404 Page not found error'

adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <practical translate="title" module="practical">
            <title>New Practical</title>
            <sort_order>999</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/index/index</action>
        </practical>        
    </menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

refresh your cache, logout then login again

Comment: Earlier I only cleared chche. So it did not work. But after logout and login back, i got my custom template. There was no any coding errors